# How can we achieve password validators in Angular?

Tags: angular

[How can we achieve this using Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m0WD.png)

I need to turn all the errors to turn green if no errors, I need all error conditions should turn green as I shown in the figure

Comment: Do you have any code to show which didn't worked for you. If yes then you can add the failed code in the post to suggest you some solutions. [You can go through this doc](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validator-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom control error that return an array of objects

Imagine some like

```
passwordError(){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>
    {
        const errors=[
                     {error:false,text:"Must be at least 8 characters!"},
                     {error:false,text:"Must contain at least 1 number!"},
                     {error:false,text:"Must contain at least 1 in Capital Case!"}
                     ....
                    ] 
        if (control.value.length<8)
              errors[0].error=true;
 
        if (!control.value.match(/.*\d{1}.*/))
              errors[1].error=true;

        if (!control.value.match(/.*[A-Z]{1}.*/))
              errors[2].error=true;

        ....

        return errors.find(x=>x.error)?{error:errors}:null

    }
  }
```

See that the function return null if no errors or an object `{error:THE ARRAY}`. Each element of the array has a property `error` true or false and a text -to know the "Must containt" use Reg Expressions-

You can use some similar to

```
control=new FormControl("",this.passwordError())
```

So, when you use

```
<div class="resume-error" *ngIf="control.errors">
  <div *ngFor="let error of control.errors.error" [class.error]="error.error">
      {{error.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

show all the text with class "error" or not

So, you use a .css like

```
.resume-error div::before
{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:1rem;
  height:1rem;
  margin-top:.125rem;
  margin-bottom:-.125rem;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 4a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 4zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z'/></svg>") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.resume-error div
{
  color:red;
}
.resume-error div:not(.error)
{
  color:green;
}
.resume-error div:not(.error)::before
{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:1rem;
  height:1rem;
  margin-top:.125rem;
  margin-bottom:-.125rem;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="green" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z"/></svg>') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tagovj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)